# Underapproximating the exponential function from below

Tags: inequality, reference-request, exponential-function

I think that for positive natural numbers *t* and *n* we have

$$
\left(1+\frac{n}{t}\right)^t\ \le\ e^n\,.
$$

1. Is this true? I have constructed a proof of it (which would probably take some lengthy typesetting here, and further I believe that the inequality could be ***very*** standard), but I wish to have an independent confirmation from the folks here.
2. If the answer to the previous question is "yes", is there a proof in the published, reviewed literature (book, article, thesis, etc.) that I can reference? We really don't want to show that we've reinvented the wheel.

EDIT: Since the answers confirmed the inequality, and there are even duplicate questions, I'm really interested in part 2 from now on.

Comment: "which would probably take some lengthy typesetting here": respondents on this site are not reluctant to lengthy typesetting. But none is eager to do all the hard work for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove $\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n < e^x$, where $x$ is any positive real number and $n$ is any positive integer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1645220/prove-left1-fracxn-rightn-ex-where-x-is-any-positive-real-numbe)

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/8925, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1466039, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1142400 – all found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cleft(1%2B%5Cfrac%7Bn%7D%7Bt%7D%5Cright)%5Et%5C%20%5Cle%5C%20e%5En%24&p=1)

Answer (score 0):

You Can prove by so many methods that $\forall s\ge0, \log(1+s)\le s \tag{1}$

Now use $(1)$ with $s={n\over t}$ and take exponential of both side

---

$$ \log\big(1+\frac{n}{t}\big)\le \frac{n}{t}\iff  t\log\big(1+\frac{n}{t}\big)\le n\iff  \log\big(1+\frac{n}{t}\big)^t\le n\iff\left(1+\frac{n}{t}\right)^t\ \le\ e^n$$